# make element visible to upload file using selenium and python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

here is the Html snippet:

```
 <div class="ia-ControlledFilePicker"><input class="ia-ControlledFilePicker-control icl-u-visuallyHidden" type="file" id="ia-FilePicker"><label class="ia-ControlledFilePicker-fakeControl" for="ia-FilePicker">Choose file</label><span class="ia-ControlledFilePicker-info">No file chosen</span></div>
    <input class="ia-ControlledFilePicker-control icl-u-visuallyHidden" type="file" id="ia-FilePicker-resume">
```

Here is the CSS bit:

```
.icl-u-visuallyHidden {
border: 0;
clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
height: 1px;
margin: -1px;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 1px; }
```

Objective: upload file to the page using selenium python.I can't click on the "choose file" button from selenium either, because it's hidden.

Things I have tried so far to make the element visible that don't work:

```
    # change_visibility = "document.setElementById('ia-FilePicker').style.visibility='visible';"
    # changWebElemente_display = "document.setElementById('ia-FilePicker').style.display='block';"
    # self.driver.execute_script(change_visibility)
    # self.WebElement.execute_script(change_display)
```

## #

```
    # change_height = "document.getElementsByClassName('ia-FilePicker.ia-ControlledFilePicker-control.icl-u-visuallyHidden').style.height='100px';"
    # change_width = "document.getElementsByClassName('ia-FilePicker.ia-ControlledFilePicker-control.icl-u-visuallyHidden').style.width='100px';"
    # self.driver.execute_script(change_height)
    # self.driver.execute_script(change_width)
```

## #

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ia-FilePicker.ia-ControlledFilePicker-control.icl-u-visuallyHidden#ia-FilePicker-resume"))).style.display = "block" )
```

And many more. I've been working on this for days.

Error: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'style' of null .

I also know about AutoIT, but I want to stick with Selenium on Chrome and Python for now. What can I do? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make the field visible with setting opacity

```
self.driver.execute_script("document.querySelector(\"input[id*='ia-FilePicker-resume']\").style.opacity='1'");
```

and then try to upload file

Comment: `self.driver.execute_script("document.querySelector(\"input[id*='ia-FilePicker-resume']\").style.opacity='1'")
        file_input = self.driver.find_elements_by_id("ia-FilePicker-resume")
        file_input.send_keys(os.getcwd() + '/resume.txt')` I still have the same error.